# Filter ip traffic based on certain packet bits

Tags: cisco, packet-capture, java

I want to capture ip traffic at a linux machine based on the following bpf filter:

```
ether[45]=0x11 and ether[68]=0x34
```

Incoming traffic is around 20Gbps and the filter discards 95% of the traffic. As my linux machine gets overloaded, I want to put a hardware filter in front of it.

Can someone suggest a solution?
Can a cisco router provide such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

1. There's `net.core.bpf_jit_enable`, have you tried enabling it?
2. There's U32 which I guess could also be used for the purpose of your task.

Comment: 1. I don't want to filter on kernel as it overloads my server
2. what is U32 except for submarine?

Comment: [U32](http://www.lartc.org/howto/lartc.adv-filter.html#LARTC.ADV-FILTER.U32) is a classifier used by `tc`. It lets you match against arbitrary bit patterns in a packet in the kernel, usually for routing purposes or to mark them for later handling by `iptables`.

Comment: @JamesSneeringer, don't bother — he doesn't want it to be software (read it would "load his server"), instead he prefers some kind of transistor based circuit built exclusively for that task. ;-P

Comment: It could probably be done with a custom Cisco NBAR definition, since it does allow matching of arbitrary bits in a packet, and some Cisco platforms do NBAR in hardware. You'd match the NBAR definition in a class-map, and then handle (probably drop) non-matching packets in a policy-map. However, I don't know if NBAR can meet the requirement of multiple matches in the same packet. I've never done it before, so I don't feel comfortable submitting it as an actual answer.